# Tengo este error con listas en c "[Error] request for member 'siguiente' in something not a structure or union"

Tags: c, lista

Al tratar de compilar me da el error

> ```
> [Error] request for member 'siguiente' in something not a structure or union
> ```

y no entiendo por qué.

Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodo
{
    int dato;
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
} Nodo;

typedef Nodo *list;
typedef Nodo *pnodo;

//Nodo *inicio,*inicio2,*ultimo,*ultimo2;

void agregar_lista1(list *inicio,list *ultimo);
void agregar_lista2(list *inicio2,list *ultimo2);
void mostrar_lista();

int main ()
{
    int op;
    list inicio = NULL,inicio2 = NULL,ultimo = NULL,ultimo2 = NULL;
    do
    {
        printf ("MENU");
        printf ("\nOp1 Ingresar nodo en la lisata 1");
        printf ("\nOp2 Ingresar nodo en la lisata 2");
        printf ("\nOp3 Mostar los datos almacenados en la lista");
        printf ("\nOp4 Mostrar suma de las listas anteriores\n\n");
        scanf ("%d",&op);
        switch(op)
        {
        case 1:
            agregar_lista1(&inicio,&ultimo);
            break;
        case 2:
            agregar_lista1(&inicio2,&ultimo2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mostrar_lista(inicio);
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        }
    }
    while (op!=4);

    return 0;
}

void agregar_lista1(list *inicio,list *ultimo)
{
    Nodo *nuevo;
    nuevo = malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    if (nuevo==NULL)
    {
        printf ("\nNo se pudo crear el nodo\n");
    }

    printf ("Ingrese un numero entero positivo: ");
    scanf ("%d",&nuevo->dato);

    if (inicio == NULL)
    {
        nuevo->siguiente = *inicio;
        *inicio = nuevo;
        *ultimo  = nuevo;
    }
    else
    {
        /* en la linea de abajo es donde me da el error */
        *ultimo->siguiente = nuevo;
        *ultimo = nuevo;
        nuevo->siguiente = NULL;
    }
}

void mostrar_lista(list *inicio)
{
    pnodo ptr;
    *ptr = inicio;
    if (inicio != NULL)
    {
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            printf ("\nDato %d \n",ptr->dato);
            ptr = ptr->siguiente;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\n\nLa lista esta vacia\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: En los otros casos (Cualquier otro fuera de ese "else") te da error al querer asignarle un Nodo a siguiente ?

Comment: Ninguna otra linea me lanza ese error, solo esa

Comment: Según el compilador puede tirar error en la línea `nuevo->siguiente = (*inicio);` error: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes colocar paréntesis, de esta manera:

```
(*ultimo)->siguiente = nuevo;
```

Esto debido a la precedencia de los operadores.
Saludos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias era justamente eso.

Comment: Siempre a la orden

Comment: @JoseIgnacioGonazález Si esta respuesta te sirvió, por favor marcala como aceptada

Comment: tira error  en la línea nuevo->siguiente = (*inicio); error: assignment from incompatible pointer type